# document Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm newbie in JavaScript and want to ask a base question. When `document` is creating and what's the lifecycle of this object? As i understood, document is a client-side object. Is it true? When `document` is destroy by garbage collector?

Comment: if you're dealing with a browser environment, then document will NEVER be destroyed until the browser leaves the current page, because document **IS** the current page.

Comment: @MarcB but, can the page javascript observe the document be no longer reachable? Say, from _another_ window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working in a browser-based environment, `document` is everlasting. Immortal. `document` simply refers to the current page you're on. Go to your Javascript console in your browser. Try assigning something to `document`, then see what the value of `document` is. It won't have changed. If you're *not* running it on the browser, then `document` has no special meaning, and you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Excelent, your dispel my doubts!